# Problems with touch events after view moved

Tags: android, android-layout, translate-animation

I'm working on a simple sliding-drawer component. It's a similar to the deprecated SlidingDrawer component.

I'm extending LinearLayout (because that suits what I need to do).  I'm not doing anything very fancy, just a handle that you click on to open and close the drawer.

My drawers are contained in a RelativeLayout, and for opening and closing it uses a TranslateAnimation to reposition the view mostly off-screen (with just the handle showing).

The problem I am having is that when the drawer is closed, the child components inside the drawer are responding to touch events at the same screen position as if the drawer was open - even though they are clearly not in that position.

For my right-hand drawer this is particularly bad because the area where you should be able to click the handle does not work, as the event is being handled instead by the component that would be in that position if the drawer were open.

It's really odd. I tried a requestLayout on the drawer in the onAnimationEnd event, but that did not help (in desperation I also tried invalidate and forceLayout - also did not work). I've also tried calling the requestLayout on the parent view.

Any thoughts on what else I could try?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the weird touch events occur because the view is translated, and for whatever reason this translation is not also applied to the touch region - go figure.

I resolved the problem by clearing the animation (which removes the translation), and then repositioning the view using layout params.  Here's a snippet...

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
    drawer.clearAnimation();
    MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) drawer.getLayoutParams();
    switch (drawer.mAlign) {
    case ALIGN_LEFT:
        lp.leftMargin = x2;
        break;

    case ALIGN_RIGHT:
        lp.rightMargin = -x;
        break;

    case ALIGN_TOP:
        lp.topMargin = y2;
        break;

    case ALIGN_BOTTOM:
        lp.bottomMargin = -y2;
        break;

    }
    drawer.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

*x2* and *y2* are the final x and y positions calculated earlier for use in the *TranslateAnimation*, and then reused here.

**Note:** On the animation I use *setFillAfter(true)*. You can potentially leave this out, and then you also don't need the *clearAnimation()* later, but I found that doing this caused a flicker.

I hope this helps others. I'm a bit of a noob to Android, so very happy for any corrections or better ways of handling this!

Answer (score 0):

The pre-3.0 animation system only updates the drawing for a given view, not its actual bounds including touchable areas.

You can use the newer animation properties (you'll need 9OldAndroids if you want to support pre honeycomb), or set the draw view to gone after the animation to slide it off has finished.

You could also try playing with offsetLeftAndRight

Comment: This is still a problem even in Android 4.4 using the ObjectAnimator API

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem